# Ajax call fails in Firefox & safari but works fine in chrome

Tags: ajax, laravel, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am trying to perform an action using an ajax call, all works fine in chrome but when i make the same action in firefox or safari browser, it throws the request in error.
i can see in networks tab that call is made to url but no status is provided and then calling back the referer page with laravel error "MethodNotAllowedHTTPException".
I am adding my code also.

```
function transactionAction(value, id, amount){  
//event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("formSubmitButton").disabled = true;
var SITE_URL = "{{url('')}}" + ('/web/v1/dispute-refund');
var actionId = value;
var pId = id;
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
    url:SITE_URL,
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{
        actionId:actionId,
        pId:pId,
        amount:amount,
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    success: function (response){
        $('.refund').modal('hide');
        if(response.result.status == true){
        $('.error-divbox-master').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible"><h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>'+response.result.message+'</h4></div>').delay(10000).show().fadeOut('slow');
        document.getElementById("formSubmitButton").disabled = false;
        }else{
          $('.error-divbox-master').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>'+response.result.message+'</h4></div>').delay(10000).show().fadeOut('slow');
          document.getElementById("formSubmitButton").disabled = false;
    }
    setInterval(function(){location.reload();},3000);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $('.refund').modal('hide');
        $('.error-divbox-master').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>'+response.result.message+'</h4></div>').delay(10000).show().fadeOut('slow');
        document.getElementById("formSubmitButton").disabled = false;
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your headers to this -

```
headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },
```

Comment: Have a look at this, it may help you. The URL needs to be absolute and the page you are posting to needs to match the token in your header.  https://laravel.io/forum/04-03-2014-simple-ajax-post-response-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 0):

Try **method: "POST"** Instead of  **type: 'POST'**